# php embeded javascript parse error php tags causing "syntax error: expected expression, got <"

Tags: javascript, php

there is a failure of my php script to parse. The Mozilla error console gives me syntax error: expected expression, got < can anyone tell me what is wrong with my script. any help is much appreciated.

thankyou

```
<?php  
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

function returnimages($dirname=".") {
$pattern="\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$";
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if(eregi($pattern, $file)){
echo 'galleryarray[' . $curimage .']=["' . $file . '"];' . "\n";
$curimage++;
}
}

closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}

echo "var galleryarray=new Array();" . "\n";
returnimages();
?>
```

Comment: Is this showing up in your browser source? If so your server isn't executing PHP, it's just sending it through raw.

Comment: Is it possible that `$curimage` or `$file` contain characters that are not acceptable array key names?

Comment: Visit the js file directly. It doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Are sure the php is executed and not returned as plain text, so  the error could be the `<` from the opening `<?php` line?

Comment: Why those `[]` around `$file`?

Comment: well this is my js file I'm racking my brain to find the error any help would be appreciated

Comment: var galleryarray=new Array(); 
    var curimg=0
    function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute                              ("src", "slideshow_images/"+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
    }

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 2500)
}

Comment: the php file is not showing In the browser source code

Comment: this is the js script

Comment: var galleryarray=new Array(); 
    var curimg=0
    function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute  ("src", "slideshow_images/"+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
    }

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 2500)
}

Comment: the exact error in the console is

Comment: syntax error: expected expression. got <

Comment: hey I am having the very same error, are you using pushState by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with your PHP script as far as I can see. I ran the test locally and it returned:

```
var galleryarray=new Array();
galleryarray[0]=["PHP-logo.svg.png"];
galleryarray[1]=["PHP_Logo.png"];
```

I'd guess that there's another problem with your JS. Can you paste your source code & the exact error you're seeing in console?

Comment: var galleryarray=new Array(); 
    var curimg=0
    function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute   ("src", "slideshow_images/"+galleryarray[curimg])
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}

window.onload=function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 2500)
}

Comment: I'm afraid all of that seems to work for me. I created a simple test like so:

https://gist.github.com/pemcconnell/06cf1a39f929c45cb55b

It correctly loops through some test images in a ./imgs

Note: I disabled the javascript header as I created an inline test (using just one file)

Does the PHP code definitely render correctly?

Comment: thanks for your help pmcconnell, I haven't got it working yet but I will take a look at your script and see if I can work it out - klein

Comment: hi I have ran your script pemcconnell on my webserver changing the image folder but i'm getting a broken image instead of the images from the image folder.  it has made me wonder if my file execute permissions are wrong i'm sure the file paths are correct running your script and my website.  but thank you for your coding help it gave me a smaller script to experiment on.